# How do I find out which motorcycling group is legally active in North Carolina (NC)? To lobby for legalizing lane splitting

Tags: united-states, lobbying

I have been riding in California and I have seen the benefits of lane splitting. I'm getting conflicting info online about the legality of [lane splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lane_splitting) in NC.

I want to get involved with the government and legalize lane splitting. I would like to know which motorcycle groups are active in lobbying in NC so I can support them. Can I email my senator and ask which motorcycling groups is politically active in his constituent?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I'm inexperienced with politics. How do the sites differ from each other. I read through the sidebar and the question does seem inline with what the site needs

Comment: This site is about what the law is, not what it should be. That's politics.

Comment: "Legally active" is unfixably vague. A person can be legally active, as can a group of any size. Individuals or groups don't have to be chartered by NC or created under NC law to be able to speak up about public issues.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica by legally active I meant they are invovled with lobbying, attending public hearings etc.

Comment: What is lane splitting? It would be useful to include that in your question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to contact these groups themselves? Use google to find local motorcycle advocacy groups, then contact them to find out their views on this issue and whether they're politically active. Even if they're not, they probably know more about the motorcycle community than any politician.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write to your senator, but don't expect much of a reply.  It's not their job to do the research for you.

Moreover, your senator is there to represent your state to the federal government.  But issues of North Carolina law are not a matter for them. The senators have no vote in the NC legislature.

Instead I suggest typing "motorcycle club north carolina" into your favourite internet search engine.  It found https://www.facebook.com/nccomc/ The North Carolina Confederation of Motorcycling clubs.  From there contact the clubs and ask if they are politically active, and if they fit your outlook.

You can contact your state representatives or senators directly, or you can directly contact members of the NC standing committee on Transport https://www.ncleg.gov/Committees/CommitteeInfo/HouseStanding/45 Again, not to ask them about motorcycle clubs, but to ask them directly about lane splitting.

I can't find the link right now, but the Fociety of Friends (Quakers) have some good resources for "how to lobby".  The Quakers have long been active lobbyists, and have guides for individuals who want to lobby.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I found American Motorcyclist Association and I got in touch with one of the directors who pointed me in the right direction. I will be getting in touch with some motorcycling groups and see what they say

Comment: @RahulSundaresan if this answer helped you, it may help future readers. Please tick the green checkbox beside the answer to indicate it helped you answer your question.